# Please help me with the syntax errors in the following vhdl code that i wrote

Tags: vhdl

I used Xlinix ISE 14.1 to write the following code.

I found the syntax to be correct but the xilinx [IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uldF.png) shows errors at line 27 and 30.

I am trying to find the first partial derivatives of a matrix of numbers which is similar to finding the edges in an image.

The function by2i is used to convert the bytes (i.e. bits) to integer number.

In this VHDL code I am getting error messages:

> "ERROR:HDLCompiler:806  B:/gxgyVHDL.vhd" Line 27: Syntax error near "return".
>   "ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "B:/gxgyVHDL.vhd" Line 30: Syntax error near ","".

I am unable to correct these errors as I know very little in VHDL. I learned basic programming in VHDL like implementing MUX, counters etc.

This is the first time I am writing a program for image processing And I'm not sure whether this program works like expected but it works well matlab and python.

Please help to correct these errors.

Here is vhdl code:

```
enter code here
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use IEEE.math_real.ALL;

entity getGxGy is
  generic (width : natural := 66; 
           height : natural := 130); --width and height of the image window.

Port( pxl : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        clk : in bit;
         fv : out real); --need to configure 'fv' signal properly to appropriate bit vector.
end getHOGfv;

architecture behave of getGxGy is

function by2i (b : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)) return natural is
  variable num : natural;
  begin
    num := 0;
    for i in b'Range loop
      if b(i) = '1' then
        num := num + 2**i;
      end if;
    end loop
   return num
end by2i;

type bufarr is array (1 to height, 1 to width) of natural;
type gxgy is array (1 to height-2, 1 to width-2) of integer;

--signal tempfv : mat4;

process(clk, pxl)
variable buf: bufarr;
variable gx, gy: gxgy;

begin
  --Buffer to store/create 64*128 pixels/widthindowidth
  for h in 2 to height-1 loop
    for w in 2 to width-1 loop
      buf(h)(w) := by2i(pxl);
    end loop;
  end loop;

  --1pixel padding
  for w in 1 to width loop
    buf(1)(w) := 0;
  end loop;
  for w in 1 to width loop
    buf(height)(w) := 0;
  end loop;
  for h in 2 to height-1 loop
    buf(h)(1) := 0;
  end loop;
  for h in 2 to height-1 loop
    buf(h)(width) := 0;
  end loop;

  --compute gradients
  for h in 2 to height-1 loop
    for w in 2 to width-1 loop
      gx(h)(w) := buf(h+1)(w)-buf(h-1)(w);
      gy(h)(w) := buf(h)(w+1)-buf(h)(w-1);
      mag(h)(w) := abs(gx(h)(w)+gy(h)(w));
      ang(h)(w) := gy(h)(w)/gx(h)(w);
    end loop;
  end loop;

  end process;

  end behave;
```

Comment: If you want to convert an `std_logic_vector` containing an unsigned value to a integer, just use `value_as_int <= to_integer(unsigned(value_as_std_logic_vector));`

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

1. Your entity names do not match.  That is, `entity getGxGy` does not match `end getHOGfv;`
2. You are missing a trailing `;` on the `end loop` in `by2i`
3. You are missing a trailing `;` on the return in `by2i`
4. You are missing a `begin` statement in your architecture (between the `type gxgy` and the `process(clk, pxl)`
5. Your syntax for the use of multidimensional arrays is wrong.  Rather than `buf(1)(w)`, it should be `buf(1, 2)`.
6. Neither `mag` nor `ang` are defined.

When you have a large number of errors, it can be difficult to track down the exact cause.  Often the compilers get confused at reporting the errors.  Start with the first one, fix it, and re-compile.  Continue until things cleanup.

Also, a point of clarification.  You don't need `by2i`.  You can use numeric_std to do the converstion (thanks to scary_jeff for pointing this out).  Use `to_integer(unsigned(pxl))` to do the conversion.

And one further point.  Do not use both `std_logic_unsigned` and `numeric_std` at the same time.  `numeric_std` is the standard way to use signed and unsigned numbers.  `std_logic_unsigned` was a vendor specific extension that is not standard.

Edit:  You used the following syntax to define your arrays:

```
type bufarr is array (1 to height, 1 to width) of natural;
```

This is fine.  And as I noted above you have to use the `buf(h, w)` syntax.  But you could define it differently, such as:

```
type width_array is array(1 to width) of natural;
type bufarr is array(1 to height) of width_array;
```

Which you could then index using `buf(h)(w)`.

I prefer the former.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the syntax items and missing declarations noted by PlayDough there are two superfluous context clauses for packages numeric_std (which should not be mixed with the Synopsys arithmetic pages std_logic_unsigned) and math_real (which isn't yet used).

After all the changes are edited in:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;
-- use ieee.math_real.all;

entity getgxgy is
  generic (width : natural := 66; 
           height : natural := 130); -- width and height of the image window.

port( pxl : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        clk : in bit;
         fv : out real); -- need to configure 'fv' signal properly to appropriate bit vector.
end getgxgy;            -- WAS gethogfv;

architecture behave of getgxgy is

    function by2i (b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return natural is
        variable num : natural;
    begin
        num := 0;
        for i in b'range loop
            if b(i) = '1' then
              num := num + 2 ** i;
            end if;
        end loop;  -- MISSING ';'
       return num; -- MISSING ';'
    end function by2i;

    type bufarr is array (1 to height, 1 to width) of natural;
    type gxgy is array (1 to height - 2, 1 to width - 2) of integer;

    --signal tempfv : mat4;

begin  -- for architecture modiy WAS MISSING

    process (clk, pxl)
        variable buf: bufarr;
        variable gx, gy: gxgy;
        variable mag, ang: gxgy;  -- MISSING DECLARATIONS

    begin
      --buffer to store/create 64*128 pixels/widthindowidth
        for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
            for w in 2 to width - 1 loop
                buf(h, w) := by2i(pxl);  -- WAS  buf(h)(w)
            end loop;
        end loop;

        --1pixel padding
        for w in 1 to width loop
            buf(1, w) := 0;                -- WAS buf(1)(w)
        end loop;
        for w in 1 to width loop
            buf(height, w) := 0;           -- WAS buf(height)(w)
        end loop;
        for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
            buf(h, 1) := 0;                -- WAS buf(h)(1)
        end loop;
        for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
            buf(h, width) := 0;            -- WAS buf(h)(width)
        end loop;

    --compute gradients
        for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
            for w in 2 to width - 1 loop
                gx(h, w) := buf(h + 1, w) - buf(h - 1, w); -- WAS gx(h)(w), buf(h+1)(w) and buf(h-1)(w) 
                gy(h, w) := buf(h, w + 1) - buf(h, w - 1);  -- WAS gy(h)(w), buf(h)(w+1) and buf(h)(w-1)
                mag(h, w) := abs(gx(h, w) + gy(h, w)); -- WAS mag(h)(w), x(h)(w) and gy(h)(w)
                ang(h, w) := gy(h, w) / gx(h, w); --WAS ang(h)(w), gy(h)(w) and gx(h)(w)
            end loop;
        end loop;

    end process;

end architecture behave;
```

your code analyzes and elaborates, noting there is no assignment to `fv`, type REAL is not synthesis eligible and there is no synthesis eligible use of `clk`.

If `clk` were std_logic (or std_ulogic) you could use the std_logic_1164 function rising_edge.

Adding a recognized sequential logic RTL construct for a clock edge gives:

```
    process (clk) --  pxl NOT NEEDED , pxl)
        variable buf: bufarr;
        variable gx, gy: gxgy;
        variable mag, ang: gxgy;  -- MISSING DECLARATIONS

    begin
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          --buffer to store/create 64*128 pixels/widthindowidth
            for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
                for w in 2 to width - 1 loop
                    buf(h, w) := conv_integer(pxl);  -- WAS  buf(h)(w)
                end loop;            -- CHANGED to use conv_integer
            end loop;

            --1pixel padding
            for w in 1 to width loop
                buf(1, w) := 0;                -- WAS buf(1)(w)
            end loop;
            for w in 1 to width loop
                buf(height, w) := 0;           -- WAS buf(height)(w)
            end loop;
            for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
                buf(h, 1) := 0;                -- WAS buf(h)(1)
            end loop;
            for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
                buf(h, width) := 0;            -- WAS buf(h)(width)
            end loop;

        --compute gradients
            for h in 2 to height - 1 loop
                for w in 2 to width - 1 loop
                    gx(h, w) := buf(h + 1, w) - buf(h - 1, w); -- WAS gx(h)(w), buf(h+1)(w) and buf(h-1)(w) 
                    gy(h, w) := buf(h, w + 1) - buf(h, w - 1);  -- WAS gy(h)(w), buf(h)(w+1) and buf(h)(w-1)
                    mag(h, w) := abs(gx(h, w) + gy(h, w)); -- WAS mag(h)(w), x(h)(w) and gy(h)(w)
                    ang(h, w) := gy(h, w) / gx(h, w); --WAS ang(h)(w), gy(h)(w) and gx(h)(w)
                end loop;
            end loop;
        end if;

    end process;
```

also noting the switch to the package std_logic_unsigned function conv_integer from using function `by2i`.

So these changes along with deleting the function by2i analyzes.

Genning up a testbench to look for bounds errors:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity getgxgy_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of getgxgy_tb is
    signal pxl:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal clk:  bit;
    signal fv:   real; 
begin

DUT:
    entity work.getgxgy
        port map (
            pxl => pxl,
            clk => clk,
            fv => fv
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 120 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

And we elaborate and run the testbench and get a run time error!

The error is division by zero in the assignment to `ang`, so your algorithm needs a bit of work still.

Blocking that with an if statement and we find there's a bounds error in the assignment:

```
    gx(h, w) := buf(h + 1, w) - buf(h - 1, w); -- WAS gx(h)(w), buf(h+1)(w) and buf(h-1)(w)
```

And that's caused by hitting `w` = 65 when

```
    type gxgy is array (1 to height - 2, 1 to width - 2) of integer;
```

type `gxgy`'s second dimension corresponding to `w` has a range to `width - 2` while `w` reaches `width - 1` which is out of bounds.

So a bit more algorithmic expression tuning still to do.

It isn't particularly clear what you intend to register. If it's just `fv` that could occur in a different process, with the current processes sensitivity list set to just `pxl` and `gx`, `gy`, `mag` and `ang` made into signals.

It's likely that all the abs, multiplies and divides may not fit in a target FPGA, requiring operations be spread over some number of clocks using common resources for arithmetic operations.  VHDL describes hardware and every operator invocation or function call can imply it's own hardware.

In synthesis a loop statement has it's sequence of statements 'unrolled' and where no interdependencies are found produce separate hardware. For h in 2 to height - 1 and w in 2 to width - 1 ranges in your nested loops your generic values are implying 8001 subtracts for each of `gx` and `gy`, abs and addition for `mag` and divides for `ang`, all from changing the value of `pxl`.  This tells us your hardware isn't going to fit in any FPGA without sharing resources over some number of clocks, a time and space tradeoff.

So not only does your algorithm need a bit work, you need to take implementation resources into account.

You don't program in VHDL you describe hardware.

Comment: "You don't program in VHDL you describe hardware." Amen. I think I'm pretty free with most constructs in my code (loops, functions, occasional procedure, arrays and records), but I always have a hardware architecture in mind. And I know what the code will (or should) produce in real hardware. VHDL is a means to an end; a tool.

Comment: Thank you so much. Today I learnt a lot. It helped me very much.